# Getting an error at Dialog.show

Tags: android

I am running 4 background tasks in a activity. But I was getting an error in one activity at 
pDialog.show(). I am unable understand the. For some activities I got the same problem but I removed the progress dialog because those are medium priority but this one I need High priority. Here is my error. Can any tell me how to solve this error.

```
09-28 19:44:53.575: I/Choreographer(1120): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120): Activity com.example.newairways.Gscan has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d40860 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.newairways.Gscan has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d40860 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at com.example.newairways.Gscan$insert.onPreExecute(Gscan.java:304)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at com.example.newairways.Gscan$1.onClick(Gscan.java:201)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-28 19:44:54.374: E/WindowManager(1120):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 19:44:57.234: E/Trace(1146): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Handler` to show dialog if you are using `AsyncTask` or `Thread` in your program. And if the problem still exists, please try posting your code for further help :)

Answer (score 0):

All progress dialogs should be closed before exiting an activity.
You have probably forgotten to close your progressDialog.

Close it in your onPostExecute() method

```
    pDialog.dismiss();
```

Check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) for more clarifation on windowleaked error.

Comment: Ya I closed it on postExecute() method